# OpenMP как оптимальней декларировать цикл

Tags: c++, c, openmp

Как более правильно описать цикл примерно для следующей схемы кода:

```
int len = size of ebytes;
int tlen = 0;
uchar *ebytes = ...входящий буфер данных;
uchar *obytes = ...из ходящий буфер данных;
uchar *ubuf = calloc(1,256);

/// вот тут сложности понимания
#pragma omp parallel private(tlen) schedule(dynamic) reduction(+:ebytes) reduction(+:obytes)
do
{
  int sz = 256;
  memcpy((void*)ubuf, (void*)ebytes, sz);
  ebytes += sz;
  tlen += sz;

  func (ubuf, &sz);

  memcpy((void*)obytes, (void*)ubuf, sz);
  obytes += sz;

} while (len > tlen);
```

с циклами типа `for` все более-менее понятно, но переходить на цикл тут не очень охото из идеологических соображений.

Кажется придется переделывать.

Comment: В каждом цикле вы определяете обьект `sz`  и держите обьект `tlen`  в общей видимости. Лучше конечно в цикле for определять sz один раз и  `tlen` увеличивать  от .. до . Ну и  вопрос: зачем нужно явное приведение в void* в  memcpy((void*)ubuf, (void*)ebytes, sz);?  Можно же просто   memcpy((ubuf, ebytes, sz);

Comment: `sz` изменяется в `func()`, приведение лишнее, согласен, но не в нем суть. И я так понимаю что без `for` не обойтись? И у меня сомнения, ubuf будет уникальным для каждой итерации? с учётом что память на него выделяется один раз выше цикла?